# pandas dataframe update column values based on other columns of the corresponding row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas *dataframe* as:

```
Name    abc_1   abc_2   abc_3   abc_4   abc_5   abc_6   cde_1   cde_2   cde_3   cde_4   cde_5   cde_6
 xyz    True    True    False   False   False   True    True    True    False   False   False   False
 stu    False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   True
 vwx    False   True    False   False   False   False   True    True    False   False   False   False
```

For a given *row*, any *abc_x* column should be updated to *True* if corresponding cde column is *True* **AND** ***at least*** one of the *abc* column of the corresponding row is *True*.

Result: *abc_1* of *vwx* row becomes *True* but *abc_6* of *stu* row remains *False* as below:

```
Name    abc_1   abc_2   abc_3   abc_4   abc_5   abc_6   cde_1   cde_2   cde_3   cde_4   cde_5   cde_6
 xyz    True    True    False   False   False   False   True    True    False   False   False   False
 stu    False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   True
 vwx    True    True    False   False   False   False   True    True    False   False   False   False
```

Seems, using *iterrows* and then by iterating each column is the option. But I have several and very large *dataframes* and looking for a pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider transform your columns to multi-index and then perform element wise operation on `abc` and `cde` columns:

```
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_", expand = True)
df['abc'] = (df['abc'] | df['cde']).apply(lambda col: col & df['abc'].any(axis=1))
```

[image]

You can join multi-index to one level column afterwards if you prefer:

```
df.columns = ["_".join(col) for col in df.columns]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
abc = df.filter(like='abc')
cde = df.filter(like='cde')

df.update((abc | cde.values).__and__(abc.any(1), 0))
df
```

[image]